# NetBeans Loading But Does not Start

Tags: netbeans

Previous to installing the latest version of the NetBeans IDE 7.2 I uninstalled my previous version. The ide does not start. I see the hour glass for a few seconds in my Windows Vista and disappears and nothing happens. I am left with no IDE to run. Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: Check `Processes`. Do you have `NetBean` or `Java` here?

Answer (score -2):

Install NetBeans 7.4, because that's the latest, more features rich and more stable.